# React Hot Reloader 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hot-loader

I'm trying the new [React Hot Loader 3](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/commit/64f58b7010a1b2a71ad16716eb37ac1031f93915) and I'm receiving an warning message:

> warning.js:44 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null,
>   undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM
>   elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render
>   method of `AppContainer`.

This is the App file.  What is wrong?
*Ps: It's written the same way as on examples.*
*Ps2: The problem is not in the App since it renders on the render() outside the if statement*
*Ps3: The warning only appears when the browser tries to 'hot-reload' (when I make changes to any file)*

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import a11y  from 'react-a11y'
import Store from './stores/Store';
import App from './components/App/App';

const store = new Store();

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  a11y(React);
}

render(
  <AppContainer
    component={App}
    props={{ store }}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App/App', () => {
    render(
      <AppContainer
        component={require('./components/App/App').default}
        props={{ store }}
      />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't component={require('./components/App/App').default} just be component={App}?  What is the purpose of requiring the same component again (inline, mind you) and attempting to use a .default property?

Comment: It's how it's written in Dan examples. If I change to component={App} I don't receive the error, but the component doesn't hot reload neither.

Comment: I see...  it's some sort of major upgrade to how the hotloader works, and it's in alpha atm... Can you verify the hotloader version in your package.json file as well as your plugins/entry arrays in the webpack/babel config?

Comment: It was conflicting with another babel plugin (add-module-exports). I've removed it, and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the problem was with my .babelrc file. I had some other plugins, that I've removed, and it worked:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015-loose", "react", "stage-1"],

  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ],
}
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you listed which plugins you removed.